# Add frequency based on duplicate row

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, `dd`

```
     Var1 Freq
76   2189- 1181
458  6186-  813
445  6170-  738
902  61801  650
74   2181-  618
504  6268-  509
905  61804  307
500  6259-  272
910  61889  265
495  6253-  242
73   2180-  224
510  6256- 6407
461  6180- 3254
792        2333
1          2312
467  6186- 2259
212  4019- 1254
4561 6170- 1162
462  6181- 1156
80   2189- 1154
465  6184- 1035
```

I would like to search for duplicates in the `Var1` column and combine them, creating a sum of the frequencies int he `Freq` column such that...

```
     Var1 Freq
76   2189- 2335
458  6186- 3072
445  6170- 1900
902  61801  650
74   2181-  618
504  6268-  509
905  61804  307
500  6259-  272
910  61889  265
495  6253-  242
73   2180-  224
510  6256- 6407
461  6180- 3254
792        2333
1          2312
212  4019- 1254
462  6181- 1156
465  6184- 1035
```

NOTE: So you don't have to go searching for the differences, the `Var1` values combined were `2189-`, `6186-`, & `6170-`.

I imagine this can be done with some fancy work with `[]` and `duplicated()`, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I'd appreciate any guidance.

The `dput` for this data can be [found on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WQfrzdmh).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be done with simply

```
aggregate(Freq ~ Var1, dd, sum)
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dd)[, .(Freq = sum(Freq)), by = Var1]
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))
```

though this will add up the empty entries of `""` too, which is not clear why you treat them differently

Either way, with `data.table` you could reach your exact output using

```
setDT(dd)[, if(Var1 == "") .SD else sum(Freq), by = Var1]
#      Var1   V1
#  1: 2189- 2335
#  2: 6186- 3072
#  3: 6170- 1900
#  4: 61801  650
#  5: 2181-  618
#  6: 6268-  509
#  7: 61804  307
#  8: 6259-  272
#  9: 61889  265
# 10: 6253-  242
# 11: 2180-  224
# 12: 6256- 6407
# 13: 6180- 3254
# 14:       2333
# 15:       2312
# 16: 4019- 1254
# 17: 6181- 1156
# 18: 6184- 1035
```

Comment: Thanks @david-arenburg. Treating "" differently was simply an oversight. What a simple solution.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Just now saw the OP's comments.  Yes, it is ugly.  I would wish `summarise` to be a bit more flexible

Comment: @Arun I was too lazy to install `1.9.4` in order to test, but I was under the impression that if `Var1` is in the `by` statement, I can't use it in `j` prior to some updates in v > = 1.9.5?

Comment: David, No. What you're referring to is a [different issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/497)..